# Can't figure out SimpleAudioPlayer.CrossSimpleAudioPlayer, it most likely cannot find the file (System.Reflection.TargetInvocationExceptio)

Tags: c#, android, audio, xamarin.forms

My attempted implementation

```
      using INWORK.Models;
using INWORK.Services;
using INWORK.Views;
using MvvmHelpers;
using Plugin.SimpleAudioPlayer;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Xamarin.Essentials;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace INWORK.ViewModels
{
    public class AboutViewModel : ViewModelBase, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public AboutViewModel()
        {
            //MessagingCenter.Subscribe<ViewModelBase>
            Task.Run(async () => await Refresh());
            Title = "About";
            OpenWebCommand = new Command(async () => await Browser.OpenAsync("https://aka.ms/xamarin-quickstart"));
            var player = Plugin.SimpleAudioPlayer.CrossSimpleAudioPlayer.Current;

            player.Load(GetStreamFromFile("SmallBeep.wav"));
            player.Play();
        }

        public ICommand GoInfoCommand { get; set; }

        private Stream GetStreamFromFile(string filename)
        {
            var assembly = typeof(App).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
            var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("ĪNWORK." + filename);
            return stream;
        }

        public async Task Refresh()
        {
            Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5), () =>
            {
                if (StaticClass.refreshbool == true)
                {
                    StaticClass.refreshbool = false;

                    Loadup();
                    StaticClass.passedbool = true;
                }

                return true;
            });
        }

        public ICommand OpenWebCommand { get; }
    }
}
```

[image: context for further text]
Context for further text
I have attempted to add the file to the android solution(in drawable and assets) as AndroidResource and Embedded resource
as well as Embedded resource in the main Assets folder(i do not know if the assets folder needs  to be declared somewhere), but all attempts so far have resulted in the same error

[image]
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: 'Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.'

Comment: first, if you get a `TargetInvocationException` you need to look at the `InnerException` property for more details.  Second, you are trying to load a resource from the shared project, but you have placed the wav file in the Android project.  It needs to be in the shared project as an embedded resource, and you need to be sure the correct resource path is used when loading it.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/data/files?tabs=macos#loading-files-embedded-as-resources

Comment: What you are saying was indeed the case, the path was incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want it for Android you can place it in Assets folder of Android Project as **AndroidAsset** and not **AndroidResource** like you did. Then play it with:

```
Plugin.SimpleAudioPlayer.ISimpleAudioPlayer player = Plugin.SimpleAudioPlayer.CrossSimpleAudioPlayer.Current;
_ = player.Load("beep.wav");
player.Play();
```

Answer (score -1):

I was being a bit of an idiot, but just in case anyone is having problems with this
[image]

Put in main folder as `embeddedresource`:

```
var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("INWORK.Assets." + filename);
```

Whole path needs to be defined with dots and then everything works great